# Why features on WCS projected subplot are in the wrong place in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, projection, astropy

I have a fits file about an astronomical object. I can plot it like this:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

hdul = fits.open(fitsfilename)[0]

wcs = WCS(hdul.header)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdul.data)
```

This works, and produces a nice pic:

[image]

I would like to add some additional features to this plot, which doesn't work. For example lets try to add a circle to 119°, -67°30'. I expand the code by:

```
plt.scatter([119],[-67.5],c='r',s=500)
```

What I get is:

[image]

Which is really not what we wanted, the circle is around 118°5', -67°5', not where it is supposed to be (119°, -67°30').

What am I getting wrong, or what is a good fix to this issue?

---

Note: when I run `wcs = WCS(hdul.header)`, I get a warning:

> WARNING: VerifyWarning: Verification reported errors:
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'A_2_0' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '3.29341755408e-05').  Fixed
>   'A_2_0' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Note: astropy.io.fits uses zero-based
>   indexing.  [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'A_1_1' is not FITS standard (invalid value string:
>   '1.51709339878e-05').  Fixed 'A_1_1' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'A_0_2' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '5.17973753556e-06').  Fixed
>   'A_0_2' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'B_2_0' is not FITS standard (invalid
>   value string: '2.97627426087e-06').  Fixed 'B_2_0' card to meet the
>   FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'B_1_1' is not FITS standard (invalid value string:
>   '2.71948126373e-05').  Fixed 'B_1_1' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'B_0_2' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '1.66848449653e-05').  Fixed
>   'B_0_2' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'AP_1_0' is not FITS standard (invalid
>   value string: '1.79541533196e-06').  Fixed 'AP_1_0' card to meet the
>   FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'AP_0_1' is not FITS standard (invalid value string:
>   '9.20624843151e-07').  Fixed 'AP_0_1' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'AP_2_0' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '-3.29292923201e-05').  Fixed
>   'AP_2_0' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'AP_1_1' is not FITS standard (invalid
>   value string: '-1.51738446887e-05').  Fixed 'AP_1_1' card to meet the
>   FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'AP_0_2' is not FITS standard (invalid value string:
>   '-5.18321445978e-06').  Fixed 'AP_0_2' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'BP_1_0' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '8.99029048217e-07').  Fixed
>   'BP_1_0' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'BP_0_1' is not FITS standard (invalid
>   value string: '1.15967736014e-06').  Fixed 'BP_0_1' card to meet the
>   FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'BP_2_0' is not FITS standard (invalid value string:
>   '-2.97837492348e-06').  Fixed 'BP_2_0' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'BP_1_1' is not
>   FITS standard (invalid value string: '-2.71998518336e-05').  Fixed
>   'BP_1_1' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
>   WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'BP_0_2' is not FITS standard (invalid
>   value string: '-1.66872388359e-05').  Fixed 'BP_0_2' card to meet the
>   FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card
>   'WCSR_PRJ' is not FITS standard (invalid value string: '3.6679e-07'). 
>   Fixed 'WCSR_PRJ' card to meet the FITS standard.
>   [astropy.io.fits.verify] WARNING: VerifyWarning: Card 'WCSR_PIX' is
>   not FITS standard (invalid value string: '8.2565e-05').  Fixed
>   'WCSR_PIX' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]

So this might be relevant; question of how to fix it still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot in [world coordinates](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/overlays.html#world-coordinates), you need to specify the `transform`, e.g.:

```
ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter([34], [3.2], transform=ax.get_transform('world'))
```

Generally, you can ignore those FITS header warnings, since none of the FITS header cards there are related to the WCS (afaik).

Comment: Here I am trying to implement what you said: https://github.com/zabop/GaiaToTESS/blob/master/to_keflavich.ipynb
The marker is not where I imagine it is supposed to be. Would you be able to say why? (& thanks for the answer thats already helpful)

Comment: I wrote a more elaborate explanation of what I am doing, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116787/how-to-plot-gaia-astrometry-data-to-tess-images-using-python

Comment: That example.... actually looks like a bug, since you tried to plot something at coordinates RA=16, dec=-72 and got something plotted at RA~17.25 Dec~71.(something).    That's weird and I don't immediately know what to make of it.  Try plotting a few other points and see if there's a consistent offset.  Also, it's a bit strange that your RA is in degrees here instead of hours.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem right. Plotted some more points, and expanded this question to include a plot with the example points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116787/how-to-plot-gaia-astrometry-data-to-tess-images-using-python 
Maybe the axis are not as we expect them to be, they might show where hte RA and DEC values are on the axis, but these lines are not parallel with the imshow() plot (and this I think can be expected, since TESS' field of view is not aligned with constant RA&DEC lines).

Comment: Now I believe this method is right, thanks for the nice answer.