# SIP-compatible Python plate solving package

Tags: astropy

I need to perform accurate pixel to world coordinate transformations on FITS files that were originally created using Maxim DL. Maxim uses Pinpoint for plate solving which generates TRi_j distortion coefficients. These are incompatible with the astropy.wcs coordinate transformation functions which I was proposing to use as these assume SIP distortion coefficients.

I'm therefore looking for options to re-platesolve the FITS files to generate SIP coefficients.

So far all I've found is astrometry.net but this is an on-line service. I'm really looking for offline platesolving (preferably against a local copy of the GSC) that I can perform synchronously as part of my app's workflow.

Are there any Astropy-affiliated (or other) Python packages that perform SIP-compatible platesolving against the GSC?

Alternatively, are there any equivalents to wcs.all_pix2world that can use TRi_j distortion coefficients so I can work with the Maxim DL data?

Many thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SIP coefficients, the astropy.wcs methods will work with [TPV distortion coefficients](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/registry/tpvwcs/tpv.html). This means you can use the output of the [SCAMP astrometric solver](https://scamp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) directly with astropy.wcs. If you wish to convert TPV coefficients to the SIP form, you can use the [sip_tpv package](https://github.com/stargaser/sip_tpv) for which I am the lead contributor. I don't know of a Python package wrapping SCAMP -- I have wrapped it for the [Zwicky Transient Facility pipeline](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2018/david_shupe.html) but that code is not public.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

hdul = fits.open(fitsfilename)[0]

wcs = WCS(hdul.header)

ax = fig.gca()
ax.scatter([34], [3.2], transform=ax.get_transform('world'))
```

([Based on this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109929/why-features-on-wcs-projected-subplot-are-in-the-wrong-place-in-matplotlib).)